# Download a file from server using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, download

I searching for a way to enable the user select a file exists on the server and download it using angularjs  , I found this code which didn't work , so does anyone have a way that works right

```js
 var content = 'file content';
    var blob = new Blob([content], { type: 'text/plain' });
      $scope.download = function () {

        $window.location = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
    }
```

```html
    <input type="button" value="download" download="content.txt"   ng-click="download()"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way:

```
<a href="download.txt" data-file-download="true">Download</a>
```

and use the directive:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive('fileDownload', [function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            replace: true,
            template: '<button class="btn btn-default" data-ng-click="download()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span></button>',
            controller: ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$element', '$attrs', 'dialogs', '$timeout', function ($rootScope, $scope, $element, $attrs, dialogs, $timeout) {
                $scope.progress = 0;

                function prepare(url) {
                    dialogs.wait("Please wait", "Your download starts in a few seconds.", $scope.progress);
                    fakeProgress();
                }
                function success(url) {
                    $rootScope.$broadcast('dialogs.wait.complete');
                }
                function error(response, url) {
                    dialogs.error("Couldn't process your download!");
                }

                function fakeProgress() {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        if ($scope.progress < 95) {
                            $scope.progress += (96 - $scope.progress) / 2;
                            $rootScope.$broadcast('dialogs.wait.progress', { 'progress': $scope.progress });
                            fakeProgress();
                        }
                    }, 250);
                }

                $scope.download = function () {
                    $scope.progress = 0;
                    $.fileDownload($attrs.href, { prepareCallback: prepare, successCallback: success, failCallback: error });
                }
            }]
        }
    }]);
```

this uses the jQuery fileDownload function to download the file. (note: there is also the dialogs class in effect)

Comment: Ii've included filedownload jquery library but still results in the following error (Error: $.fileDownload is not a function)

Comment: hm, I included jquery and the jquery.fileDownload plugin

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.8.2, should this conflict ?

Comment: I think if you are using this one: https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload then it should be ok. It says jQuery 1.6+. To be sure, you can make a fiddle or so which uses this versions.

Comment: ok, i made a demo http://jsfiddle.net/dea3nsx2/1/, but you have to replace download.zip with a valid url to a file.