# how to download image in browser -angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am showing image list in a html table. I have one column in the table as image name and made it as link so user can click and download the image. The image list come from database which are saved as byte array and while sending to client side I am converting it to static object as shown below
given below

```
FileContent = Utilities.GetString(item.FileContent);
//GetString method
public static object GetString(byte[] bytes)
{
    try
    {
        MemoryStream stPictureSource = new MemoryStream(bytes);

        var sr = new StreamReader(stPictureSource);

        return sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Logger.Log(ex);
        return string.Empty;
    } 
}
```

So,Can some one have an idea, how to download image in browser.
Please let me now if the question isnt clear...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27034530/download-a-file-from-server-using-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Comparison your Tags included angularjs and asp.net-web-api, This sample App showing how to do file uploads with angularjs using Asp.net Web Api. Hopefully it can aid you to deal with your problem.[angular-fileupload-sample](https://github.com/stewartm83/angular-fileupload-sample)

[image]

Comment: I need to download image..anyway thanks for answering.

Comment: it can download image. you can try it first.